# Computer Audio Over Network

Tags: audio, home-networking, kvm-switch

I've got a computer tower that I'd like to relocate to the basement for noise and heat reduction purposes, leaving the monitor and KB/mouse in the office.  I can use a KVM over IP HDMI extender for those functions.  However, I'd also like to occasionally be able to listen to whatever sound is being produced on the computer.

Basically, I just want to be able to plug headphones into something in the office, and hear whatever sounds are being generated by the computer's 3.5mm audio jack, e.g. Youtube or system sounds.  Basically the same thing I could do if the computer was still in the office.

Bottom line: I want to be able to use my computer remotely from the basement the same way I would in the office. I have the KVM side solved, but not the audio side.

What options do I have for the audio side?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A wireless HDMI transmitter works in my home. It carries both video and audio from my living room to an amp in my room which has speakers and headphones attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need [extender of audio cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K3WYDIE). Be aware this extender can work with headphones, but I have my doubts you will be able to use microphone. And If you do not have intermediate amplifier you probably can't use two of them to extend the distance.

You can use also HDMI to [traverse also the sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI)

P.S. No affiliation with manufacturer or seller

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your operating system. If it's GNU/Linux [PulseAudio can be networked](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/), assuming you have another device to act as the sink.

You said you're using HDMI. HDMI also carries audio, and many HDMI monitors have headphone ports. Can't you use that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Well, after trying a couple of KVM over IP extenders, it seems those aren't ready for primetime, at least not over consumer-grade networks (my gig network is apparently unsuitable).  They seem to work OK directly connected via ethernet.  So I just went ahead and ran a pair of CAT8 cables from the basement directly to the office—out the basement wall, up the exterior of the house, into the attic, across the attic floor, down the walls to keystone ports in the walls.

As to audio, the KVM extender I found has ports for headphone and mic (don't need the latter).  However, at one of the two locations I want to have a digital audio signal so I can set up a 5.1 setup, and I found this HDMI audio extractor that will seemingly do the job.  It also does headphone, which would let me switch between speakers and headphones.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B084T4QDFP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084T4QDFP)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 3.5MM plug to BlueTooth adapter like [this](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=3.5mm%20to%20bluetooth%20receiver&hvadid=557288143389&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9008492&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=15023541098593228620&hvtargid=kwd-902676522429&hydadcr=5027_13159989&tag=googhydr-20&ref=pd_sl_2qcqq0exme_e).  Then you just need to connect a BlueTooth headset or speakers to hear.

Comment: That would assume the Bluetooth signal could reach from the basement—through two floors—to my office.  My BT earbuds crap out when I leave my phone in my car and walk 50' away to get a tool.  That's *outside* with no structures between.

Comment: @Huesmann Thats correct, but you dont have to buy a cheap BT transmitter.  There are some that can transmit very far.  Of course, they cost more.